# Unable to delineate inundation map from HEC-RAS to Hec-GeoRAS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, error, hec-ras, hec-geohms

I am trying to delineate the flood map generated from HEC-RAS by importing them into the HEC-GeoRAS. However, I got this error:

[image]

How will I resolve this?

Comment: For errors it's usually best to actually copy the text and paste it into the answer rather than just post a picture. With a picture the text can't be searched on. Might want to take a look at http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vq00000007010316 or https://geonet.esri.com/thread/75837

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem recently. Resolved it by placing the DEM directly on the local drive (something like C:\GeoRAS\dem). Ensure that the DEM is in Grid format (no extension) and has a simple name with no special characters.